# Change appearance TemplateField from C #

Tags: c#, asp.net

Add this to a GridView and now I would like cambial the background color or text showing from code

How can I do it?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="01">
      <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="falta1" runat="server" > </asp:DropDownList>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate> 
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c1") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: you want to change the background of which element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. How about...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" ControlStyle-BackColor="Black">
```

You can just hit the space bar within the control tag to see a list of options for different properties, like ControlStyle.

On a side note, you'll get better responses if you post things you've already tried along with your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind, you have to access the label using FindControl in RowDataBound event and then change the color,text of the label.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      Label oLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
      if(oLabel != null)
      {
           //oLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;//See below for cambial
           oLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC99");
           oLabel.Text = "MyText";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello
but without using a single view event it is